# Java compiler displays "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc::mysql://localhost:3306/test" though there is driver

Tags: java

This is the picture of compilation.Though I have included "mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar" in libraries, the compiler says "No driver found exception" everytime when I compile the program. What can I do now to solve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQdGf.jpg)

Code is:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Check
 {


    public static void main(String [] args){
    int found=0;     
    String pass=null;
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.println("PASSWORD: ");
         pass=s.next();

      Connection con;
      boolean st =false;
      try{

         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          try {
               con= DriverManager.getConnection
                                ("jdbc::mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","");

               PreparedStatement ps =con.prepareStatement
                                                    ("SELECT * FROM mytable where Name=?");



              // Connection cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/medicalstore","root","");




              ps.setString(1, pass);
              ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();
              if(rs.next())
              do{
                    if(rs.getString(2).equals(pass)){
                      //con.close();
                        System.out.println("FOUND");
                            found=found+1;
                                break;
                  }

              }while(rs.next());
                  }catch(Exception e){

                System.out.println("EXCEPTION CAUGHT: "+e);
                  }



      }catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
            if(found==0)`
         System.out.println("NOT FOUND");               
      }

}
```

This is the code for the program.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Please paste your code in the question and not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
"jdbc::mysql://localhost:3306/test"
```

it should be

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
```

Just an additional colon between jdbc and mysql.